# missing FROM-clause error with rails engine mounted in application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

The following scope in a rails engine:

```
module GolfApi
  class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
      scope :club_same_name, -> { Course.joins(:club_location).where('club_locations.name=courses.name')}
  end
end
```

when executed in an application that is loading the engine gives the following error:

```
PG::UndefinedTable - ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "club_locations"
LINE 1: ...d" = "golf_api_courses"."club_location_id" WHERE (club_locat...
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The where clause is being executed by SQL without being namespaced with GolfApi, so there is a need to prefix tables in the where clause with golf_api_, so the scope should be

```
scope :club_same_name, -> { Course.joins(:club_location).where('golf_api_club_locations.name=golf_api_courses.name')}
```